# Importing Snort Log Files into WireShark

Tags: wireshark, snort

I ran snort as follows

```
sudo /usr/sbin/snort -m 027 -b -l ./snortLog -u OtagoHarbour -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -S HOME_NET=[192.168.0.0/16] -i eth0
```

./snortLog received the files alert and snort.log.1381507400.  I want to examine the log file with WireShark.  I started up WireShark, chose Import and entered the name of the log file in the Input Filename field.  Then I clicked OK.  I got a message about saving the previous captured packets.  I selected "Continue without saving" and it proceeded with no error messages.  However the packet listing window is completely empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Wireshark are you using ?

In any case, if you just "started up Wireshark" and opened a file you should not have gotten any message about "saving previous captured packets".

To read an existing pcap(tcpdump) binary file (which is what I think you have since
    you specified -b to snort).

1. Start Wireshark
2. Do File ! Open
   Do *not* use File ! Import.